# MySQL using Count in different way

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've researched about this code:

```
select *,
  year(curdate())-year(dbirth) - (right(curdate(),5) < right(dbirth,5)) as age 
from       resident_info 
having age = 18;
```

but what i wanted is after getting all info that already 18 I wanted to count them. Is there any way i could enter two query at the same time or any solutiomn for my problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: You need 2 Query. One to gather all the records and one that counts it. If you just need the count on code side, you can get the size of the result set from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, if you need the `count` of these, then you can use:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select *,
   year(curdate())-year(dbirth) - (right(curdate(),5) < right(dbirth,5)) as age 
  from       resident_info 
 having age = 18
) src
```

If you want to return all of the data from `resident_info` and the `count`, then you can use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select *, 
   year(curdate())-year(dbirth) - (right(curdate(),5) < right(dbirth,5)) as age,
   src.Total
from resident_info 
cross join
(
    select count(*) Total
    from
    (
        select year(curdate())-year(dbirth) - (right(curdate(),5) < right(dbirth,5)) as age 
        from  resident_info 
        having age = 18
    ) x
) src
having age = 18
```

Comment: can i ask you one more question i used your second code and it ended like this: SELECT * , YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( bday ) - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( bday, 5 ) ) AS age
FROM resident_information
CROSS JOIN (

SELECT COUNT( * ) Total
FROM (

SELECT YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( bday ) - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( bday, 5 ) ) AS age
FROM resident_information
HAVING age =23
)x
)src
HAVING age =23 how can i use total to put it in a field ot text field?

Comment: @janmark you should be able to access the value from the `SELECT` statement.  See my edit, I added `src.Total` to the select list.

Comment: can i ask one more what  if i wanted to add 1 more condition where color = 'red'; where should i put it in this code select *, 
   year(curdate())-year(dbirth) - (right(curdate(),5) < right(dbirth,5)) as age,
   src.Total
from resident_info 
cross join
(
    select count(*) Total
    from
    (
        select year(curdate())-year(dbirth) - (right(curdate(),5) < right(dbirth,5)) as age 
        from  resident_info 
        having age = 18
    ) x
) src
having age = 18

Comment: @janmark If you want to apply the `color=red` filter to the total count and the final product, then you would have to include the where clause in two places in the inner query and the outer query

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
select temp.*,
   year(curdate())-year(dbirth) - (right(curdate(),5) < right(dbirth,5)) as age 
       FROM resident_info AS temp
       WHERE age = 18;
```